# Attack Web Forms dvwa to achieve lfi

Tags: web-application, dvwa, lfi

Does anyone know how to hack dvwa(http://www.dvwa.co.uk) via submitting a form input like `../../../../../etc/passwd` to expose the `/etc/passwd` of a given server?

Is there a endpoint to hit for this?

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/@Aptive/local-file-inclusion-lfi-web-application-penetration-testing-cc9dc8dd3601

Comment: Yes I saw this for in the `url` but not via a form field... do you know where to find that

Comment: You wont find it in DVWA.But you can code it yourself.Simple take the filename via post request instead of GET and in the backend include that file without any validation.

Comment: @VipulNair can you please provide a sample?

Comment: sample of what?

Comment: @VipulNair - How to do this: Simple take the filename via post request instead of GET and in the backend include that file without any validation

Comment: I dont have the laptop right now.I will write you the code in a few hours

Comment: Wow, thanks @VipulNair - look forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $file=$_POST['filename'];
include($file);
}?>
    <html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <p>filename<input type="text" name="filename"><p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is usually the vulnerable back end code for Local file inclusion.If you intercept the request and change the filename parameter you can read data from the victim server.This code can also result in remote file inclusion if allow_url_include is turned on.